# Will implicit data type conversion in SQL affect performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 samples that effectively do the same thing --
Sample 1:

```
command.Parameters.Add(ParamFoo, SqlDbType.Int)
command.Parameters(ParamFoo).Value = fooVal
```

Sample 2:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(ParamBar, barVal)
```

Which sample would be recommended? I know that the second sample is making some conversions. Wouldn't it be best to not require conversions and go with the first sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you posted your code, is completely irrelevant. Both variants will perform identically, there will be no way you can measure the cost of in-client converts against the huge background of the database call.

However, there is a very very big known problem when barVal is of type String. The SqlClient will add the parameters as type NVARCHAR and when used in SQL expressions in comparing with a VARCHAR column, the SQL [type precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) will require the *column* to be converted to NVARCHAR instead of the variable to be converted to VARCHAR, and this changes index seeks into table scans and has disastrous performance consequences.

Comment: +1 for the warning and explanation about the implications of the type precedence rules on (N)VARCHAR

Comment: I guess, if I am reading this correctly, for `String` data types, I should opt for the two-line sample (#1).

Comment: For strings, if tthe parameter is compared with varchar columns (as in `SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE name=@name` where `name` id varchar) you should absolutely make sure that the parameter is added as SqlDbType.Varchar, or modify the command text to force force the comparison as varchar: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE name=cast(@name as varchar(...))`

Comment: Excellent. I'll definitely take care of this.